# Modifying WSARecv data

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2

It is necessary to modify the unencrypted data that the server sends before it is received by the client.

```
int WSAAPI __WSARecv(SOCKET s, LPWSABUF lpBuffers, DWORD dwBufferCount, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRecvd, LPDWORD lpFlags, LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine)
    {
        int result = _WSARecv(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesRecvd, lpFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);
        // The original WSARecv must be called to fill the lpBuffers buffer
        
        if (lpBuffers->buf[0] == 0x09 and lpBuffers->buf[1] == 0x00 and lpBuffers->buf[2] == 0x12)
        {
            // 09 00 12 32 00 00 FFFFFFFD FFFFFF8D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     
            char replace[] = { 0x33, 0x00, 0x02, 0x2F, 0x7B, 0x22, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x72, 0x61, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x5B, 0x22, 0x5C, 0x75, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x63, 0x65, 0x58, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x30, 0x31, 0x54, 0x65, 0x52, 0x5C, 0x75, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x65, 0x20, 0x31, 0x22, 0x5D, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x22, 0x22, 0x7D, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
     
            lpBuffers->buf = replace;
            lpBuffers->len = 64;
     
        cout << "replaced" << endl; // Writes to the console, which means it works, but the game still sees the same data
    }
 
    return result;
}
```

lpOverlapped and lpCompletionRoutine are zero. TCP protocol.

Ideally, I would like to be able to prevent unwanted data from reaching the client, but as I understand it, this is not possible without writing a proxy server or an external interceptor (such as Wireshark).

Comment: You created `__WSARecv` as a thunk to `_WSARecv` in your client code to filter messages? `lpBuffers->buf = replace` initializes buf with a pointer to a local variable that will be destroyed after exiting from `__WSARecv`.

Comment: @nevilad I intercepted the WSARecv function using Detours. When WSARecv is called, it is redirected to __WSARecv. The original function is in _WSARecv. As for the pointer, why does the game see the data then? After all, in theory, I overwritten with a pointer that was destroyed.

Comment: The pointer will point to stack. After exiting `_WSARecv` this stack space will be reused and other data will be written there. Thus your application will receive garbage. Why can't you write to the original buffer (`lpBuffers->buf`) with `memcpy`? But that's possible only when it's size is bigger than your fake data.

Comment: According to you, it should get garbage, but the data that I tried to replace reaches and the game somehow reads it. If I make it a global variable, does it help? Do I have to restore the pointer to the buffer?

Comment: If you make it a global variable it helps only in the way that it will be not overwritten. But when the caller reads from the buffer it passed and not from `lpBuffers->buf`, this solution will not help.

Comment: You do not know any way to simply prevent this data from reaching the client? So that the client, with all this, thinks that they did not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WSARecv` logic is complex, the easiest usage scenario is when it receives data immediately (overlapped not used) and the caller reads only to one buffer (`dwBufferCount == 1`).
This function handles this scenario, rewriting the receive buffer and updating number of bytes received accordingly:

```
int WSAAPI __WSARecv(SOCKET s, LPWSABUF lpBuffers, DWORD dwBufferCount, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRecvd, LPDWORD lpFlags, LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine)
{
    int result = _WSARecv(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesRecvd, lpFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);
    // The original WSARecv must be called to fill the lpBuffers buffer

    // Check WSARecv received the data, read was to one buffer, received data satisfies our pattern.
    if (!result && dwBufferCount == 1 && lpBuffers->buf[0] == 0x09 && lpBuffers->buf[1] == 0x00 && lpBuffers->buf[2] == 0x12)
    {
        // 09 00 12 32 00 00 FFFFFFFD FFFFFF8D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        char replace[] = { 0x33, 0x00, 0x02, 0x2F, 0x7B, 0x22, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x72, 0x61, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x5B, 0x22, 0x5C, 0x75, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x63, 0x65, 0x58, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x30, 0x31, 0x54, 0x65, 0x52, 0x5C, 0x75, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x65, 0x20, 0x31, 0x22, 0x5D, 0x2C, 0x22, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x22, 0x22, 0x7D, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        if( lpBuffers->len >= sizeof( replace ) )
        {
            memcpy( lpBuffers->buf, replace, sizeof( replace ) );
            cout << "replaced" << endl; // Writes to the console, which means it works, but the game still sees the same data

            // Update lpNumberOfBytesRecvd
            if (lpNumberOfBytesRecvd)
                *lpNumberOfBytesRecvd = sizeof( replace );
        }
        else
          cout << "Cannot replace - buffer too small (" << lpBuffers->len << " bytes)" << endl;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The caller typically calls and reads the data in such way:

```
char buffer[DATA_BUFSIZE];
WSABUF DataBuf;
DataBuf.len = DATA_BUFSIZE;
DataBuf.buf = buffer;

rc = WSARecv(..., &DataBuf, ....);

data = buffer[0];
```

Thus changing the value of `lpBuffers->buf` will not help, since the caller does not use it. When the caller uses it this way

```
data = DataBuf.buf[0];
```

replacing buffer address will work. Thus replcing contents of a buffer is a better solution.